# javascript function should return array, instead returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, request

I am writing a web scraping application. I can write this as a single script, and it will return a the array as desired. When modularizing my code, and turning it into functions, the code that should return an array returns undefined. Any pointers would be great.

```
"use strict";
let request  = require("request");
let  cheerio = require("cheerio");

function isNotUndefined(value){
  if(value !==undefined){
    return value;
  }
}

function scrapeIndexPage(url){
  var arr = new Array();
  request(url, function(req,error,body){
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    var view = $("div.view-content");
    view = view.html();
    $ = cheerio.load(view);
    for(var i=1;i<60;i++){
      var getClass = ".class-row-"+i+" a";
      var link = $(getClass).attr("href");
      arr.push(link);
    }
    arr = arr.filter(isNotUndefined);
  });

  return arr;
}

var url = 'http://www.urlhere.com';
console.log(scrapeIndexPage(url));
```

Comment: You fell in async trap.

Comment: You should always get an empty array since `scrapeIndexPage` returns before the callback passed to `request` is called.

Comment: if it's an async issue `arr` should be `[]` not `undefined` as OP stated ... unless that was inaccurate.